# SpagoBI: a script data set using a query data set result

Tags: javascript, database, groovy, fiware, spagobi

In spagoBI there are many ways to create a data set: script (using Groovy or Javascript), data base query
but I want to create a script data set based on the data base query result

For example if my data base query result returns: "ON"
My script returns a value incremented by one comparing to the last value returned
if the DB query returns OFF, the script value will be decremented by 1

Any ideas how to get data base query results in a Groovy or Javascript script to create a SpagoBI data set?

Answer (score 1):

at the moment you cannot define a SpagoBI dataset that way: the script can only handle the query, not the result set.
The only way you can handle a result set result by a script is within a Birt report (look for Birt scripted dataset).
If defining a SpagoBI dataset is mandatory, you can only try to get the same result set with a SQL query, using the CASE statement.
Best regards
Davide